# angular/javascript not recognizing global variable inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I did a service that gets me a movie info from omdb api but when I'm trying to use it from my controller and push the result to my movie array it complains about

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function(omdbApi) {
    this.movie = [];
    this.getMovie = function(title, year) {
        year = typeof year === 'undefined' ? "" : year;
        omdbApi.getMovie(title, year).then(function(data){
            this.movie.push({
                poster: data.data.Poster,
                title: data.data.Title,
                actors: data.data.Actors,
                plot: data.data.Plot
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Can someone explain why is it unable to push to movie? I'm not sure it's an angular problem but from javascript point I really don't get it. I've tested that the incoming data is legit.
If I just assign the data to movie then I'm unable to access it outside the function.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is, and therefore doesn't have a `movie` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake. `this` object in your `.then()` callback does not refer to the same object of `.controller()` callback. Use a closure:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function(omdbApi) {
    var self = this; // <---- this is the key
    this.movie = [];
    this.getMovie = function(title, year) {
        year = typeof year === 'undefined' ? "" : year;
        omdbApi.getMovie(title, year).then(function(data){
            self.movie.push({
                poster: data.data.Poster,
                title: data.data.Title,
                actors: data.data.Actors,
                plot: data.data.Plot
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Another option is to use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to force a context.